# How to use the 'like' operator in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I want to select from `C_Table` where `Name='John'` and use the `like` operator. For example,

```
select Name from C_Table where Name='John' AND where Details like %Boy%
```

How do I do this?

```
(Table name is C_Table)
-----------------------------------------------
Name   |  P_No  |  C_No   |  Details          |
-----------------------------------------------
John   |  001   |  001    |  Good Boy         |
John   |  002   |  002    |  Naughty Boy      |
John   |  003   |  003    |  Very Bad Boy     |
Mary   |  004   |  004    |  Beautiful Girl   |
Mary   |  005   |  005    |  Pretty Girl      |
Mary   |  006   |  005    |  Gorgeous         |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
select name from table where name="John" and details like '%Boy%';
```

Answer (score 4):

What you said works, except only one `WHERE` is used and `%Boy%` needs to be wrapped in single quotes too:

```
SELECT Name FROM C_Table WHERE Name = 'John' AND Details LIKE '%Boy%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Very close - the `WHERE` keyword is only used once in a SQL statement, and you control the filtration (called predicates) using `AND`, `OR`.  Combinations of the `AND`/`OR` can be given precedence using matching brackets-- "(" and ")".

```
SELECT Name 
  FROM C_Table 
 WHERE Name LIKE 'John' 
   AND Details LIKE '%Boy%'
```

Something to be aware of when using wildcarding in a LIKE expression is - when an index exists on a column such as `C_TABLE.name`, if you wildcard the left side-- `name LIKE '%John'`-- the index can **not** be used.  This means the query isn't as fast as it could be.  Wildcarding the right side--`name LIKE 'John%'` doesn't have this problem.  Try not to use leftside wildcarding, if you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name
FROM C_Table
WHERE Name = 'John'
  AND Details LIKE '%Boy%'
```

This will return all rows where the Name column is 'John' and the Details column contains "Boy" (the `%` is a wildcard, so it'll match anything that has the word Boy with anything before and after it).

You only need to specify `WHERE` once, `AND`s and `OR`s after that point will extend the `WHERE` clause. Also, parameters need to be quoted when they are strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name FROM C_Table WHERE Name='John' AND Details LIKE '%Boy%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, try this

```
select * 
from C_Table
where Name='John' 
AND Details like '%Boy%'
```

Comment: Thank you I am successful with your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name from C_Table where Name='John' and Details like '%Boy%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT Name FROM C_Table WHERE Name='John' AND Details like '%Boy%'
```